# Cannot pinpoint my errors in Zkill script

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a script in cron that kills zombie processes. I need it to run hourly and display a log message when a zombie is detected. I created a bash script but I receive numerous errors including unexpected end of file.

I have tried to create the cron job, but am unsure of the process and how to set it up.

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
--admin)
        stat=`ps ax | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v "PID" | xargs -n 1 ps lOp | grep -v "UID" | awk '{print"pid: "$3" *** parent_pid: "$4" *** status: "$10" *** process: "$13}' | grep ": Z"`

        if ((${#stat} > 0));then
            echo zombie processes found:
        echo .
        ps ax | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v "PID" | xargs -n 1 ps lOp | grep -v "UID" | awk '{print"pid: "$3" *** parent_pid: "$4" *** status: "$10" *** process: "$13}' | grep ": Z"
        echo -n "Kill zombies? [y/n]: "
        read keyb
        if [ $keyb == 'y' ];then
        echo killing zombies..
        ps ax | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v "PID" | xargs -n 1 ps lOp | grep -v "UID" | awk '{print$4" status:"$10}' | grep "status:Z" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n 1 kill -9
        fi
    else
        echo no zombies found!
    fi
;;
```

Comment: You can't kill a zombie, by definition: If it weren't already dead, it wouldn't be a zombie. So zombies are already as dead as they can possibly be. Killing them won't make them more dead.

Comment: (A zombie process is effectively an entry in the process table for a process that already died, holding information about *how* it died until its parent does the job of calling `wait()` to retrieve that information and thus reaping the zombie).

Comment: it detects zombie processes and needs to run hourly and then when detected, creates a log

Comment: Creating the log is fine, if you think it's important to do so for some reason. Running `kill -9` is useless. It won't do anything, because the process *isn't there anymore*, so you can't send it a SIGKILL or any other signal.

Comment: If you've got a problem with zombies, the place to start is figuring out what their parent process is, and why that parent process isn't either `wait()`ing for them itself (and thus reaping them from the process table immediately when they die), or dying itself (and thus letting them be inherited by *its* parent).

Comment: Well, I say "fine". This whole huge pipeline is silly -- you could, and *should*, replace the whole `ps | awk | grep | xargs ps | grep | awk | grep | awk` mess with just `ps | awk`, or reading straight from `/proc` and not even needing `ps`.

Comment: That said, what's with the `read` in something you want to run from cron?

Comment: Anyhow, for your syntax errors (ie. "unexpected end of file"), a good place to start is http://shellcheck.net/. Stack Overflow asks that each question only be about *one* specific error, with the text of the error included in the question and code unrelated to that one error removed, as described in the [mcve] definition.

Comment: thank you charles, its for a class that I am taking and struggling with. I've never used  Linux. but the ps | awk? I don't understand what you mean. I'm really new at this.

Comment: `awk` is a full-fledged programming language. Instead of just using it to run tiny little things like `{ print $1 }`, you can put *all* your program's logic in just one awk invocation. So, for example, `awk '! /PID/ { print $1 }'` does the work of `grep -v PID`, by having awk itself skip any line that contains the string `PID`. Similarly, you can build up arrays, maps, or other datastructures in an awk program, and then have an `END` block that goes through all the data you collected and implements your intended logic on top of it.

Comment: That said, if someone instructed you to write a program that kills zombie processes as a teaching exercise, I question whether that person understands the UNIX process model enough to be teaching it.